# How to have foreign keys each other on doctorine2

Tags: symfony

I have two tables named 'Lesson' and 'MutorSche'

MutorSche has columns 'lessonBooked'
Lesson has columns 'booked'

I want to have foreign key  by each other.
But I am not sure the meaning of inversedBy and mappedBy.
These are my cords.
Is there anything wrong??

please help me .thanks..

```
     /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Lesson", inversedBy="booked*removethis : name of the variable in Lesson.php*")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lessonBooked", referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 

    private $lessonBooked = null;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\MutorSche", mappedBy="lessonBooked*removethis : name of the variable in MutorSche.php*")
     */
    private $booked;
```

Comment: Actually everything's fine here. Now $booked has a collection of all booked lessions, and $lessonBooked has the only lesson, linked to current entity instance

Comment: But I can watch 'booked' column in MutorSche table though,I cant check 'lessonBooked' column in Lesson table

Comment: your joinColumn belongs on the owning side : `@ManyToOne` - the mapping is not correct this way! `@ManyToOne` has  inversedBy and `@OneToMany` has mappedBy.

Comment: ehm ... and what is a MutorSche? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreign Keys are added on the owning side ( from doctrine's pov - not always what you consider being the owning side ) aka the side using inversedBy.

Which foreign key ( i.e. name="id ) plus the column name ( i.e. referencedColumnName="user_id" ) to add can be configured using the @JoinColumn annotation.

@ManyToOne is always the owning side of the relation.

Logically you can't add all foreign keys to one database entry in a column. those have to be stored on every single one of the "many" related entries.

Doctrine does not add foreign keys on both sides.

Comment: thanks,I understood.I solove the problem by using two OneToOne object.for each tables.but another problem happens I have no way to delete....SQL has deep thought....